# Unexpected behavior from React eslint

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint

I am trying to make few changes in an React App but i am it's compiling get failed and gives me these Error

```
 Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4              indent
  Line 7:1:   Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4              indent
  Line 8:9:   Expected indentation of 6 space characters but found 8    react/jsx-indent
  Line 9:13:  Expected indentation of 10 space characters but found 12  react/jsx-indent
  Line 11:1:  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4              indent
```

and I even get an error if I add an extra space ,please share how I can remove these restrictions.

Comment: You either change ESLINT rules or you change your editor settings :)

Comment: @Eddy try `npm run lint -- --fix` to fix all the ESLint errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

Two options

- Disable lint
- Change your Eslint rules

if you are using VS code as editor then just run document format command such as

`option+shift+F [for mac]`

`alt+shift+F` [for windows]